# Table isn't updating (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have script to populate table with data.

Here is my View code

```
<div class="row" id="resultTable">
<table class="table">
    <tr style="background:lightgrey">
        <th class="title">Name</th>
        <th class="title">Land</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody id="people" style="overflow-y: scroll;">

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my js function code

```
function GetPeople() {
let getpeopleurl = "/Home/GetPeopleInfo";
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: getpeopleurl,
    dataType: 'json',
    sucess: function (data) {
        let list = data;
        for (let i = 0; i <= list.length - 1; i++) {

            let peoplelist = '<td class="title">' + list[i].Name + '</td>'
                + '<td class="title"> ' + list[i].Land + '</td>';
            $("#people").append(('<tr>' + peoplelist + '</tr>'));

        };
    }
});
}
```

I checked it throught network tab and I get data

Here is screenshot

[image]

But I cannot see data in tbody. Where is my trouble?

Answer (score 0):

I found trouble.

It was in typo.

I was writing `sucess`, but it needs to be `success`